# code consolidation for the dependency injection pattern

Tags: php, object

I have this function in 3 classes because they all use the same objects.  In the effort to not repeat the code in each class should I extract it out into a parent class?  If it is a matter of preference i'd like to.

This function was created to implmenet the dependency injection pattern ( a misnomer in my opinion as it removes depedencies).

```
public function setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject)
{
    $this->DatabaseObject = $DatabaseObject;
    $this->TextObject = $TextObject;
    $this->MessageObject = $MessageObject;
}
```

Comment: In fact, you define the depencendy outside and pass it along to the target object. That ways seen, you inject dependencies - opposed to hard-coding dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should always create DRY code wherever possible, so if it will apply to all child classes, move it to the parent class and let classes override if necessary.

Also, it is called dependency injection because you inject the dependency instead of creating it inside your class.

Comment: The Dillema being that this is would be a class with one function...I could call the function setThree or setTrinity...but what name would I give the class...my conventions are that class names are nouns...I want my code to be readable.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call your class if it's a parent class that won't be instantiated.  Also, for other reasons, I would advise you to split up your dependency injection method into three different methods, each setting only one dependency.  It makes testing, debugging, and refactoring a lot easier.